# How to solve Maven project plugin error,When I click on project the maven project it show's error as below

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, eclipse-plugin

[image]

also in windows- preferance -maven it show as below
[image]

and here i am pasting error logs,which comes when i click to create maven project.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.archetype.ArchetypePlugin.getActiveArchetypeCatalogs()" because "archetypeManager" is null
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.createViewer(MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.createControl(MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizard.createPageControls(MavenProjectWizard.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1235)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$3(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardSelectionPage.advanceToNextPageOrFinish(NewWizardSelectionPage.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage.lambda$0(NewWizardNewPage.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1542)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4068)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3645)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java. Base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java. Base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4068)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

The second error is as below
Unhandled event loop exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.archetype.ArchetypePlugin.getActiveArchetypeCatalogs()" because "archetypeManager" is null
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.createViewer(MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.createControl(MavenProjectWizardArchetypePage.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1240)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$3(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:918)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4068)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3645)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4068)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

Comment: What version of Eclipse. What version of Java is the Eclipse using? Are there any other messages in the error log - looks like a service failing to start.

Comment: @greg-449 it's sts ..Spring Tool Suite 4 

Version: 4.16.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 202209151144
 version and i cannot even click on next since it gives another error..@greg-449..AND IF i switch workspace,it's working as expected means it's working fine if i switch workspace

Comment: it's using 1.8 version of java @greg-449 and no other error log

Comment: Current versions of Eclipse won't run with Java 8 so that is not what you are running Eclipse with. Eclipse itself requires at least Java 11 and the current maven requires at least Java 17 - many Eclipse downloads include a Java 17 built in.

Comment: okay..i agreed..thanks for answering@greg-449

Comment: @greg-449 can you tell where you get the information about the need for Maven to have JDK17 ??? (https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)

Comment: @khmarbaise It is the Eclipse m2e plug-ins that interface to maven that require Java 17, not maven itself.

Comment: org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService() returned a null service object  another exception  : plugin: org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui @greg-449

Comment: then why it's work perfectly while chnanging workspace and with java 8 version @khmarbaise

Comment: Look in "Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details" "Configuration" tab to see which Java you are using. The current Eclipse will absolutely not run using Java 8. It sounds like something has become damaged in that workspace.

Comment: ohh,yes in  configuration tab it shows java.specification.version=17 @greg-449  ,It,seems that you have bright vision to see also these concepts,,

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue it mainly happens with fresh installations of eclipse or with adding a remote catalogue.

The archetype manager reads the catalogue if it gets invalid value we get that error.

## **how to solve**

The file `\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\archetypesInfo.xml` contains the archetype catalogues resetting it to the initial state solves it.

This is my template after i changed it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <archetypeCatalogs>
        <catalog type="system" id="internal" enabled="true"/>
        <catalog type="system" id="defaultLocal" enabled="true"/>
        <catalog type="system" id="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml" enabled="true"/>
    </archetypeCatalogs>
```

**Other causes**

Some people may also have upgraded to the latest 2022-12 edition of eclipse having remote catalogs in the `archetypesInfo.xml` file. They may also face the same issue changing it to the xml file also resolves this.